# Colocar contorno em div dividida

Tags: html, css

Estou a tentar colocar uma caixa à volta do meu formulário. Até aqui tudo bem, mas agora quando pretendo dividir o formulário ao meio essa mesma caixa à volta do formulário deixa de funcionar.

```
<div class="formCreate " style="width: 95%">
    <div class="divCaixa">
        <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
            <table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>Série:</td>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("Serie", (SelectList)ViewBag.Series, "", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                    <td>Nº Contrato:</td>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumDoc, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", id = "NumDoc", onchange = "validaSerieNumDocExistentes()" })</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; float: right;">
            <table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>asdasd</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando uso o `float: right` para colocar o conteúdo à direita acontece:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, a classe `divCaixa` deixa de contornar o fomulário

```
.divCaixa {
   border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
   padding:20px 20px 20px 20px; 
   border-radius: 1px;
   width:95%;
}
```

Comment: Um script para colocar o tamanho da div com o tamanho da tabela, resolveria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o div possui conteúdo flutuado, que é desconsiderado no cálculo das dimensões. Acrescente `overflow: hidden` para resolver:

```
.divCaixa {
   border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
   padding:20px 20px 20px 20px; 
   border-radius: 1px;
   width:95%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```